# Syntax error in FROM clause for simple script

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am getting a "syntax error in FROM clause" in the following script:

```
SELECT 
    a.Field2 AS ID1,
    b.Field2 AS ID2

FROM table1 AS a
 JOIN table2 AS b 
  ON a.Field1 = b.Field2 ;
```

I'm not sure what is causing this. Any indicators?

Comment: What database are you using?  Please tag the question appropriately.

Comment: just re-tagged please refer to original post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS Access requires :INNER JOIN`:

```
SELECT a.Field2 AS ID1, b.Field2 AS ID2
FROM table1 as a INNER JOIN
     table2 as b 
     ON a.Field1 = b.Field2 ;
```